# When all of $n-2$, $n+2$, $n^2-2$, and $n^2+2$ are primes?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, diophantine-equations

> Find the smallest $5$-digit number $n$ for which all of numbers $n-2$, $n+2$, $n^2-2$, and $n^2+2$ are primes.

Actually after some calculations, I realized that it should be solved using a computer. But it would be nice if you could provide a way to find this number, mathematically.

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A189051](https://oeis.org/A189051)

Comment: So I guessed right! It must be solved using a computer.

Comment: If $n$ has $5$ digits, $n^2 + 2$ will have at least $9$ digits.  I'd hate to test primality of something like that by hand.

Comment: A computational search can be made faster if you notice that n must be of the form $6k+3$ (by considering the primes mod 6).

Comment: In general, the generalized Bunyakovsky (or generalized Dickson) conjecture says that for a finite set $\{f_j(X)\}$ of polynomials with integer coefficients that are all irreducible over the rationals, unless there is some prime $p$ such that for every integer $n$ at least one of the $f_j(n)$ is  divisible by $p$, there are arbitrarily large $n$ such that all $f_j(n)$ are primes.

Comment: So in a question was "find the smallest $n$ of **at least** $5$ digits such that all of ... are primes", if the answer was "there is no such $n$" we might give a "mathematical" proof of that by showing that one of the polynomials is reducible, or by finding a prime $p$ that always divides at least one of the $f_j(n)$.  But when such an $n$ exists, you're not likely to find it except by some sort of search; mathematical cleverness might help you cut down the search space somewhat, but for the search itself you'll likely need a computer.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks for providing insights.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a computer, might as well use it.

However, for this particular problem, there are ways to optimize the search. Such as, for example, that $2$ is the only even prime among the positive integers. So if $n \neq 4$ is even, you already know that neither $n - 2$ nor $n + 2$ is prime. You can easily cut your computer's search time in half, give or take a few microseconds, just by ignoring even $n$.

Also, $n$ must be composite, because $n = 5$ is the only instance among the positive integers such that both $n - 2$ and $n + 2$ are prime. This suggests another optimization: if $n + 2$ is prime but any of the other conditions fail, increment $n$ by $4$ rather than $2$, e.g., $n = 27$, we see that $n + 2 = 29$ is prime but $n - 2 = 25 = 5^2$. Instead of moving on to $n = 29$, move on to $n = 31$.

Notice also that if $n \equiv \pm 2 \pmod 5$, then either $n - 2$ or $n + 2$ must be a multiple of $5$. Therefore you can concentrate your search on numbers having $1$, $5$ or $9$ for a least significant digit (base $10$).

I'm sure there are further optimizations you can apply. I could be wrong, but I don't think there's any mathematical algorithm that automatically guides you to the correct answer. You just have to search through the integers for the numbers that satisfy all five conditions (four primality conditions and the condition $10^4 < n < 10^5$).

Comment: A tiny suggestion . In the sentence "Also, n must be composite....", I think you meant to say that n=5 is the only instance where n, n-2, and n+2 are all prime.

Comment: For $n\pm 2$ to both be prime we must have $n\equiv 3 \pmod 6$, and since $n \not \equiv \pm 2 \pmod 5,$ we have $n,$ modulo $30,$ is congruent to one of $9,15,21.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Brilliant and simple! Thank you very much. By only looking at three out of every thirty integers, the program should deliver results very quickly.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a script in Swift that finds $n$. It can be run [here](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/594d7688e44c6d2825fc1ff9)

```
import Foundation
var n: Double = 10003

func isPrime(_ n: Double) -> Bool { //Translated from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2385999/6557621
    if n < 2 {return false}
    if n == 2 || n == 3 {return true}
    if n.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 2) == 0 || n.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 3) == 0 {return false}
    let sqrtN: Double = Double(sqrt(n)) + 1
    for i: Double in stride(from: 6, to: sqrtN, by: 6) {
        if (n.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: (i - 1)) == 0) ||    (n.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: (i + 1)) == 0) {return false}
    }
    return true
}

while !(isPrime(n - 2) && isPrime(n + 2) && isPrime(pow(n, 2) - 2) &&             isPrime(pow(n, 2) + 2)) {
    n += 2
}

print(n)
```

It prints $13761.0$